# Can I use "concerned" like this? -- "It detects [something] and extends [something] of the concerned jobs"

Tags: vocabulary

According to: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concerned

Concerned has the following meanings:

> *adjective*
>
> 1. interested or affected: concerned citizens.
> 2. troubled or anxious: a concerned look.
> 3. having a connection or involvement; participating: They arrested all those concerned in the kidnapping.

My sentence is the following:

> It detects [something] and extends [something] of the concerned [things].

I am not 100% sure whether my use of the word "concerned" is correct here. I want to say that it only extends [something] to the [things] that did [something] that was detected. The closest definition would be the third one (involved).

Is it correct to use "concerned" here? Is there a better word?

Edit: The original sentence is:

> A model detects the preemptions and extends the computation time of the [concerned] jobs.

I did not wanted to bring too much confusion with very specific words, but I understand that it might also be difficult to understand without...

Comment: Could you give an example (here in the comments is fine) of your sentence with your variable words filled in? It'll be easier for some people to read it. Namely me.

Comment: @Alexander A model detects the preemptions and extends the computation time of the jobs. (those that were preempted)

Comment: I think “related jobs” would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use *concerned*, it should be placed after the noun it modifies rather than before. Before the noun *concerned* usually means *worried* or *interested*, and it will cause readers a moment of disorientation before they figure out what you mean.

In any case, I would use *involved* rather than *concerned*. *Concerned* isn't exactly wrong—if you say *the jobs concerned* no one will misunderstand you—but it tends to be used in a more ‘active’ sense than *involved*: we tend to say that a single ‘higher’ entity is *concerned* with (or concerns itself with) multiple subordinate entities, while the subordinate entities are *involved* in the higher entity.

Employing the participle phrase *of the jobs involved* to modify both *preemptions* and *times* is entirely proper and grammatical, but it makes a complicated sentence a reader may have to read twice to understand. I would do it this way instead:

> A model detects the preemptions of the jobs involved, and extends their computation times.

---

ADDED: It now appears that ‘the jobs involved’ are not all the currently running jobs but only those which have undergone preemption. That being the case, I now think the phrase ‘the jobs involved’ is ambiguously located, and possibly ambiguous in itself; I suggest this instead:

> A model detects which jobs have undergone preemption, and extends their computation times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The term model actually refers in my context to an active module (part of software) that is based on a model. A sort of metonymy in a sense...

Comment: @Maxime In that case I'm glad I bracketed that off at the bottom! I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm still wondering if "A model detects the preemptions of the jobs involved, and extends their computation times." is the exact same as "A model detects the preemptions and extends the computation times of the jobs involved.". When I only read the first part "A model detects the preemptions of the jobs involved", I am confused: involved by what? By involved I meant "the jobs that have been preempted". Is it obvious in both sentences?

Comment: @Maxime Actually, it's not obvious in either sentence! I took your sentence to mean that the model polls the jobs involved to determines which have been preempted and consequently have had their computation times extended. Let me take another stab at this.

Comment: @Maxime Does the model then allocate additional time to the preempted jobs?

Comment: In a way, yes. (note: in the original sentence, the models detects both preemptions and migrations. So I can't use preempted jobs to refer to them)

Comment: @Maxime How 'bout this?

Comment: Looks great. Thank you! I might need to adapt it a bit though. Is it still correct if I use "the jobs that" instead of "which jobs"?

Comment: @Maxime  The Adamantine Law of Written English: Whatever can be misunderstood will be!

Answer (score 3):

Your use of "concerned" seems to be correct, but the structure of the sentence looks wrong: extends *to* rather than *of*, and *things concerned* is more idiomatic than *concerned things* (your word order suggests meaning 2, whereas you want meaning 1 or 3). It's hard to tell without the missing bits.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question. Could you suggest another way to write it?